# Silex Authentication - Restrict access after 3 missed attempts

Tags: silex

I'm new in Silex and I can not find how to change SecurityServiceProvider to restrict access for 24 hours after 3 bad connections.
The authentication works perfectly.

Thank you very much for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` which extends the `DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Create a class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;

class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
  /**
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler::onAuthenticationFailure()
   */
  public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
  {
    // create a failure counter for the access restriction

    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->options['failure_path']);
  }
}
```

share this class:

```
$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.general'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
  return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler($app['security.http_utils'], array(), $app);
});
```

where this failure handler is matching to the **firewall** named **general**:

```
// init the firewall
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
  'security.firewalls' => array(
    'general' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'
        ),
        ...
     )
   )
);
```

you will also need a `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which **extends** the `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
  /**
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler::onAuthenticationSuccess()
   */
  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
  {
    // handle the 24 hour restriction for the user ...

    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
  }
}
```

and share this class:

```
$app['security.authentication.success_handler.general'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
  return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler($app['security.http_utils'], array(), $app);
});
```

hope this helpful for you ...

Comment: Thanks for your help.
After correcting some errors like adding:                  
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

I have an other error and I don't find what argument must I pass to the method :           Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils given, Can you help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the first argument passed to CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler is wrong but I don't know what is good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ralf Hertsch for giving a clever answer, however as tekilatexee points, the Failure Handler does not accept an HttpUtils instance as first parameter to the constructor, if it extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler without overriding the constructor.

Also, you don't need to write both Custom Handlers (one for failure, one for success), you could link only a Failure Handler, or only a Success Handler.

To instance correctly your Failure Handler extending the Symfony's default, the correct definition of the handler service is like this:

```
$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.general'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler($app['kernel'], $app['security.http_utils']);
});
```

This passes the Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface as first argument to the constructor.

However, if your Custom Handler instead of extending Symfony's default, implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface` it just needs to implement `onAuthenticationFailure` that receives a Symfony's Request object and an `AuthenticationException`, and you could pass in the constructor, an instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` to log and check previous authentication failures, or any other custom set of services.